# OpenJPA Removing Entity

Tags: jpa

I'm new the JPA world and have encountered some trouble that I don't know how to solve. I was hoping someone wouldn't mind explaining to me where I've gone wrong. I have been given a database design like this:

[image]

Tables B and D are just maps and therefore are not entities. I have defined entities A, C, and E like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "B", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="C_ID", nullable=false))
    private C c;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "D", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="C_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="E_ID"))
    private List<E> e;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "E")
public class E implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "LINE")
    private String line;
}
```

A has a C, C has multiple E's.
With this arrangement I wrote tests that created a New A, then a New C and assigned it to A and then two New E's and assigned them to C and then persist A.

I then find A and delete A and ensure that it's children are removed. 
This test worked with hibernate but because our service will run on WebSphere 8 we switch our JPA implementation to OpenJPA. Under OpenJPA this test fails because OpenJPA attempts to delete entries from Table C before the entries in Table B have been deleted. This throws an exception because Table B has a foreign key constraint with Table C.

I'm hoping I've just made a simple mistake based on improper understanding on my behalf and that OpenJPA is just exposing this.

Comment: 'because our service will run on WebSphere 8 we switch our JPA implementation to OpenJPA' I don't get why you think hibernate isn't compatible with WebSphere. Maybe you forgot to exclude WebSphere built-in javax.persistence ?

Comment: Hi Gerry, thanks for the response. I was under the impression that OpenJPA and Hibernate were implementations of JPA and that Hibernate was not supported by IBM/Websphere so we are forced to use OpenJPA.

Comment: I think you got it slightly wrong. Hibernate implements JPA, and so does OpenJPA. JPA is part of Java EE, which many containers (including WebSphere) supports. However many think an implementation is not compatible while in fact it's just clashing with another one provided by the container. I suggest you try a simple hello world hibernate-JPA on WebSphere. I'm pretty confident you can make it work